# Matlab code for color transfer function is giving an error

Tags: matlab

Error using lab2rgb
Expected input number 1, LAB, to be one of these types:

single, double

Instead, its type was uint8.

Error in lab2rgb (line 52)
validateattributes(lab,{'single','double'},{'real'},mfilename,'LAB',1)

```
function outchannel = colortransfer(schannel,tchannel)
%compute mean value of source channel
img1 = imread('source.jpg');
img2 = imread('target.jpg');
SourceMean = mean(img1(:));

%compute mean value of target channel
TargetMean = mean(img2(:));

%compute normalized standard deviation of source channel 
SourceStDev = std2(img1);
%SourceStDev = normalize(std2(img1));

%compute normalized standard deviation of target channel
%TargetStDev = normalize(std2(img2));
TargetStDev = std2(img2);
% perform color transfer and obtain output channel
outchannel = (((img1-SourceMean)/SourceStDev)*TargetStDev)+TargetMean
end

% The code to call function
img1 = imread('source.jpg');
img2 = imread('target.jpg');
[S1,S2,S3] = imsplit(rgb2lab(img1));
[T1,T2,T3] = imsplit(rgb2lab(img2));
O1 = colortransfer(S1,T1);
O2 = colortransfer(S2,T2);
O3 = colortransfer(S3,T3);
montage({img1, img2, lab2rgb(cat(3,O1,O2,O3))},'Size',[1,3])

The colour transform
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty explicit. Did you check the type of the input parameter?

Comment: thank you. I will check again